# How to set up multiple PATHs in the user bash_profile in OSX 10.8?

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, cordova, osx-mountain-lion

I am looking to set up my laptop for both Python development and Phonegap Android development in OSX 10.8 using Eclipse. I installed the lastest version of Python (3.3) which added the code:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.3
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

to my .bash_profile. In process of setting up Phonegap you need to set up the PATH for the Android Development tools with the following line:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools
```

Is it possible to set up both PATHs in the .bash_profile so that Python and Android development can take place simultaneously? Or would I need to switch between the PATHs depending on what type of development I would like to do?

Comment: Please ask this question at http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Better http://unix.stackexchange.com/ as it is not Apple-specific.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you just add them both to the path list:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:${PATH}:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools"
export PATH
```

The only caveat here would be if there are sdk specific versions of python for some reason that might need executed under one of the sdk paths because the version in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin` is going to take precedence.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Both the Python commands and Android commands are working.